# What's the correct include path in this template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, include-path

I am editing file:

/templates/account/base.html

and in it want to include:

/templates/profiles/includes/sub_nav.html

I have tried the following:

```
{% block subnav %}{% include "profiles/includes/sub_nav.html"%}{% endblock %}
```

*result*: no error but no inclusion of side bar

and I have also tried

```
{% block subnav %}{% include "../profiles/includes/sub_nav.html"%}{% endblock %}
```

*result*:
Template error page: Exception Value: Caught TemplateDoesNotExist while rendering: ../profiles/includes/sub_nav.html

with following line highlighted:
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

Thus, for below, what should XXX be as contained /templates/account/base.html?

```
{% block subnav %}{% include "XXX/sub_nav.html"%}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"result: no error but no inclusion of side bar".

Logical conclusion

Your `sub_nav.html` has problems.  Or your `base.html` has problem The include is working.  It must be the HTML, CSS or Django Tags.

Comment: I've stripped sub_nav.html into a few words and it works. There must be something in it that nullifies the sidebar from being displayed in one page (but ironically in another page is displays fine.)

Comment: @Adrian33: That's a separate question.  It's difficult to pare down HTML pages to the smallest bit of Django template code that reproduces the error.  However, it's an important exercise to try and reduce the complexity of the pages to show the problem.  Sometimes, you'll find the problem while trying to create a tidy, short StackOverflow question.  That's a good thing.